# Data Matrix Barcode linked to a cell via vba hangs

Tags: excel, vba, google-api

first post so apologies if in the wrong place. (I've tried to search but was unable to find any solutions or suggestions)

I have inherited a mailing label created in an Excel sheet which pulls data from a second sheet. The label has (amongst other info) a QR code which was called thus
     https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr

I need to change the QR barcode to a data matrix barcode, in a perfect world I would have been able to change "cht=qr" to give me what I need. 
Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution?

This is the code;

```
    Option Explicit
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
'xxxxxxxxxxxxx funzioni per UDF Google Chart APIxxxxxxxxxxxxx
'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
'https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

Function URL_QRCode_SERIES( _
    ByVal PictureName As String, _
    ByVal QR_Value As String, _
    Optional ByVal PictureSize As Long = 150, _
    Optional ByVal DisplayText As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal Updateable As Boolean = True) As Variant

Dim oPic As Shape, oRng As Excel.Range
Dim vLeft As Variant, vTop As Variant
Dim sURL As String

Const sRootURL As String = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?"
Const sSizeParameter As String = "chs="
Const sTypeChart As String = "cht=qr"
Const sDataParameter As String = "chl="
Const sJoinCHR As String = "&"

If Updateable = False Then
    URL_QRCode_SERIES = "outdated"
    Exit Function
End If

Set oRng = Application.Caller.Offset(, 1)
On Error Resume Next
Set oPic = oRng.Parent.Shapes(PictureName)
If Err Then
    Err.Clear
    vLeft = oRng.Left + 4
    vTop = oRng.Top
Else
    vLeft = oPic.Left
    vTop = oPic.Top
    PictureSize = Int(oPic.Width)
    oPic.Delete
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If Len(QR_Value) = 0 Then
    URL_QRCode_SERIES = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If

sURL = sRootURL & _
       sSizeParameter & PictureSize & "x" & PictureSize & sJoinCHR & _
       sTypeChart & sJoinCHR & _
       sDataParameter & UTF8_URL_Encode(VBA.Replace(QR_Value, " ", "+"))

Set oPic = oRng.Parent.Shapes.AddPicture(sURL, True, True, vLeft, vTop, PictureSize, PictureSize)
oPic.Name = PictureName
URL_QRCode_SERIES = DisplayText
End Function
Function UTF8_URL_Encode(ByVal sStr As String)
    'http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-convert-byte-array-utf8-string-vb6.asp
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim res As String
    Dim code As String

    res = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(sStr)
        a = AscW(Mid(sStr, i, 1))
        If a < 128 Then
            code = Mid(sStr, i, 1)
        ElseIf ((a > 127) And (a < 2048)) Then
            code = URLEncodeByte(((a \ 64) Or 192))
            code = code & URLEncodeByte(((a And 63) Or 128))
        Else
            code = URLEncodeByte(((a \ 144) Or 234))
            code = code & URLEncodeByte((((a \ 64) And 63) Or 128))
            code = code & URLEncodeByte(((a And 63) Or 128))
        End If
        res = res & code
    Next i
    UTF8_URL_Encode = res
End Function

Private Function URLEncodeByte(val As Integer) As String
    Dim res As String
    res = "%" & Right("0" & Hex(val), 2)
    URLEncodeByte = res
    End Function
```

Comment: Please post an example of your data, for instance as a screenshot, to let everybody better visualize your problem.